# Auto Complete - With results retrieved from MySQL database

Tags: php, search, input, dynamic, autocomplete

I want to populate one or more names in the search field, while user type one or more characters. I used the solution got from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp. But the problem is var $countries (in my case - $cities) data shall be passed from my database.

```
<?php
    require_once("config.php"); 
    $sql = "SELECT cityName FROM city ORDER by cityName";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $city = sprintf('"%s",', $row['cityName']);    
  }

?>
```

When I echo use $city I am getting  '"Abohar","Achalpur","Adilabad","Adityapur","Adoni","Agartala","Agra","Ahmadnagar","Ahmedabad","Aizawl","Ajmer","Akbarpur","Akola","Alappuzha","Aligarh","Allahabad","Alwar","Amaravati","Ambala","Ambala', .....
But when I use -

```
var city = [<?php echo $city; ?>];

<script>
var city = [<?php echo $city; ?>];
autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), city); 
</script>
```

I get no response from the search input field. But if I copy and paste the results by echoing city, it responds and I am getting desired result. Please help me! Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure what you want but u use it as an array.
look here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: Hi JayDee, Thanks for your immediate response. I have a html search form where user will input one or more characters to get his/her desired city name. If  the characters input by users have a match in my database, will display all the matches one by one.  https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp. I took the code from here and tried to use it, it works fine, if I input all the city names statically. But if i retrieve the city names from database using while loop and replace $city in the place of cities I entered statically, not working.

Comment: Hi JayDee, Thanks for your quick response. I have a html search form, where I want to populate city names when user input one or more characters.  https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp.  - I took the code from here and tried to use it. If I input all the city names statically and assign it to $city variable, it gives desired results. When I tried to assign with a variable I retrieved from database using  while loop it not gives any result, but the last city name. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in the misuse of `sprintf` - the string is not being wrapped within single/double quotes correctly. You could perhaps simplify the PHP slightly like this:

```
require_once("config.php");

$sql="SELECT `cityName` FROM `city` ORDER by `cityName`";
$result=$conn->query( $sql );

# Fetch the entire recordset into an associative array
$data=$result->fetch_all( MYSQLI_ASSOC );

# pick the `cityName` from the array and wrap each within double quotes.
printf( '"%s"', implode('","', array_column( $data, 'cityName' ) ) );
```

Comment: Thanks Professor Abronsius, I changed my query to  - $result->fetch_all( MYSQLI_ASSOC ); and then wrapped it within double quotes. Awesome, it worked fine. But I did a small change, instead of printf( '"%s"', implode('","', array_column( $data, 'cityName' ) ) );, I changed it to  $city = sprintf('"%s",', implode('","', array_column( $data, 'cityName' ))); Because with printf, it not worked.  Thanks a lot. Awesome.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php
    require_once("config.php"); 
    $sql = "SELECT cityName FROM city ORDER by cityName";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $CityArray = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $CityArray[] = sprintf('"%s",', $row['cityName']);    
  }
    $cityAsString = implode("",$CityArray); 

?>
 // Now you can use var city = [<?php echo $cityAsString; ?>];
// You will get results in city variable now
```